# how to get input from user in this format in Python

Tags: python, matrix, user-input

I'm trying to get a input in this format(mentioned below) from python but I am unable to solve it. It would be very beneficial for me if you helped.

```
a = [[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1], 
     [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]]
```

```
n = 3
a = [int(n) for n in input("enter").strip('[]').split(',')]
print(a)
for i in range(n):
  a.append(input())
print(a)
```

The above code only helps partially.How to add the commas between two square brackets?

Comment: who would enter that ? is that in one line ? why is there `a=` in the example ? please give the exact input

Comment: How do you want `a` as? Integers, list of integers?

Comment: What you seem to want is a **list of lists**, where **each sublist is a list of integers**. Is that correct? You don't "*put commas between brackets*", you have to build the list of lists as you parse the input. Is the user expected to input that full list of lists in one line as 1 long string? Or is it 1 number at a time?